# How to select side of active vertically?

Tags: vertices, select

Does the side of active from select (Edit mode) also select upward/downward vertices?

It seems like it only selects the left right sides...

Comment: Use the Z axis option.

Comment: @lemon Where are the options? I'm just doing Select -> Side of Active, which doesn't seem to pop up an options window or anything.

Comment: that should pop up a 'select axis option'.